Difference between @Singleton and asEagerSingleton()
I have a project where I see my service is failing to initialise.
I am using Dropwizard-guicey - but it uses Guice underneath, and my question is specific for Guice because the dependency injection is the theme here.
I am attaching the link to the same question I added in Guice Github area. The project file attachment is there, (sorry SO doesn't have attachment option).
The class - TheProblemClass extends AbstractScheduledService (Guava) and implements Managed interface in Dropwizard.
The idea is that I ought to be able to start/stop the service upon Main server startup and shutdown respectively. Also, I could schedule a periodic call to one of its methods. OK - besides the sniff that it's doing 3 things in one class, it's functional.
Some things I have noticed.

When TheProblemClass is annotated with @Singleton - it is working fine.
When TheProblemClass is NOT annotated with @Singleton - it is always hanging.
In my Module - I have bound it as an eager singleton. My understanding was that I only needed to do this in one place. And the rest should be OK. Have I misunderstood how Singleton Annotation and Module Configs are supposed to be working together?


Please provide a [mre] inside the question, don't link off-site for pertinent information.

Closing because SO doesn't have an attachment option and creates verbosity for adding more and more text

You should just copy the code into a code block. That is how Stack Overflow works, and with 6K+ reputation, you should really know that already.
